# jQuery Load directly into container, fadeIn when loaded

Tags: jquery, load, fadein

I would like to load some content via Ajax direcly into a target container.

```
var theData = $('<div id="tempcontainer">').load('/'+targetProject + ' #containerUID' + targetProject);                 
$( theData ).prependTo( '#targetContainer' );
```

This loads the data into my `#targetContainer`, but leaves me with an unnecessary `#tempcontainer`.
Since i want to load multiple items into my `#targetContainer` i can't have duplicate `#tempcontainers`.

What i would like to achieve is to insert the loaded data hidden into my `#targetContainer` without having duplicate `#tempcontainers` (avoid it completely would be even better), measure it's height (whilst hidden if possible), call some functions and fadeIn when the content has loaded.

Thanks in advance!

Greetings,
Knal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`load()` is just a handy shortcut for `$.get`, so if storing the data in a variable, `$.get` is probably more appropriate. Then just hide the content, prepend it and fade it in. I do it in a different order to avoid some issues, but that does'nt matter :

```
$.get('/'+targetProject , function(data) {
    $( data ).find('#containerUID' + targetProject)
             .hide()
             .fadeIn()
             .prependTo( '#targetContainer' );
});
```

Comment: Sounds great, thanks!!

Could you explain why you'd first `fadeIn` and then `prepend`?

Comment: The fadeIn is somewhat async, so it does'nt stop the execution of the prependTo, and it's all so fast you'll never notice the difference. The reason for doing it in that order, is that I seem to run into issues with first appending / prepending, and then fading in from time to time, and this way seems to always solve those issues, so I've just gotten used to that order, as I know it always works like intended.

Comment: While testing the solution, i noticed `get` doesn't return only the desired element, indicated with `#containerUID`, whilst `load` honors this request.

Any clues?

Comment: @knalpiap - Yeah, `load()` uses a `find()` internally. It gets everything, then just filters the content as a convience. Changed the answer, and that does pretty much exactly the same.